# Flink schema evolution

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I need help restoring the flink state with the changed schema.
I have current state:

```
case class Player(id: Int, name: String)
  
private var playerState: ValueState[Player] = _ 

playerState = ctx.getState(new ValueStateDescriptor("player", createTypeInformation[Player]))
```

my Player schema has changed to:

```
case class Player(id: Int, name: Option[String])
```

and during deployment, I receive deserialization errors and can't restore the old Player state.
Is it possible to write backward-compatible deserializer?

Comment: Have you checked [State Schema Evolution](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/schema_evolution/)?

Comment: Yes, i have checked but could not find the answer/solution :(

Comment: maybe the article [Making sense of Apache Flink state migration with Scala and Avro](https://medium.com/wbaa/making-sense-of-apache-flink-state-migration-with-scala-and-avro-69091c232646) and [Evolve your data model in Flink’s state using Avro](https://medium.com/wbaa/evolve-your-data-model-in-flinks-state-using-avro-f26982afa399). Both give details about how to do it and there are also examples uploaded to a github repo